# How to return to normal user via subprocess.call(...)?

Tags: python

I use

```
subprocess.call(['sudo', 'python3'] + sys.argv)
```

to enter root from within python. Is there a way to return to the normal user after running this?

Comment: Only your subprocess here will run as root. And your parent process will continue running as the normal user. So you have to do nothing special to return to the normal user.

Comment: Oh, then I misunderstood an error I was getting in my code, thank you